# How do I count the number of letters in this Readability Program

Tags: c, count, user-input, cs50, letter

I'm trying to count the number of letters in User Input however, I keep getting 
   Segementation Fault. Could anyone tell me how to correct this issue. Thank you !

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int count_letters(int length, string array[]);

    int main(void)
    {
        string Text = get_string("Text:");
        int len = strlen(Text);
        printf("%i letter(s)\n", count_letters(len, &Text));
    }

    int count_letters(int length, string array[])
    {
        int letters = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
        {
             if (isalpha(array[i]))
             {
                 letters++;
             }
        }
        return letters;
    }
```

Comment: What is `get_string()`? Also, `string` as a type in C is very vague.  I'd expect to see `char *` or `const char *`.  Basically if string is already a pointer, you shouldn't pass it's address.  Also, turn on warnings as the compiler will tell you this information if you let it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't exactly understand what you're trying to say. I'm using get_string() for user input. I tried using char * and const char * but that leads to a number of other errors. Also there isn't a compilation issue, it just says Segmentation Fault.

Comment: I wish `cs50` and its "string" typedef would die out and those students would just be taught how how character arrays form the concept of strings.  Seems like a leaky abstraction without much benefit.

Comment: Turn on all warnings and see what the compiler says.  Also, telling what line the crash occurred will help as well.

Answer (score 0):

As in `int count_letters(int length, string array[])` the parameter `array` is already [a pointer to] an array of characters, the `[]` are wrong.

If you change this to `int count_letters(int length, string array)` and call it from `main` as `count_letters(len, Text)` the program will run.

Note that `cs50.h` already declares `string` as `char *`.

<sup>(And I agree whole heartedly with Christian Gibbins that this `string` datatype should be removed from `cs50.h`)</sup>